# docmd.runsavedimportexport vba error handling

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a macro setup to run multiple savedimportexports, but when one fails I need it to send me an email with the title of the savedimportexport that failed and continue on with the next one so I can go back afterwards and rerun the export.  I have the email portion setup, I just need to know how to place the title of the savedimportexport in the body of the email. Err.Description, Err.Number, Err.Source do not have what I need. Below is my code....

```
Function Payday_Audit_Biweekly()
On Error GoTo Payday_Audit_Biweekly_Err

DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export 1"
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export 2"
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export 3"
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export 4"
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export 5"
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export 6"
Call file_copy

DoCmd.RunMacro "CloseDatabase", , ""


Payday_Audit_Biweekly_Exit:
Exit Function

Payday_Audit_Biweekly_Err:
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem    (olMailItem)
oMail.Body = 'This is where I need the title of the SavedImportExport'
oMail.Subject = "Report Failed"
oMail.To = "myemailaddress"
oMail.SendUsingAccount = oApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
oMail.Display
SendKeys "%s", True

Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
Resume Next
End Function
```